# android socket jelly bean

Tags: android, sockets, stream, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i want to ask some question for android socket. I create a sample app to send data to wifly module. But when i receive data from module i get socket timeout exception. Without `setSoTimeout` app freeze to `inputStream.read`. Here is my code:

```
    package com.socket.wiflysocket;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final String TAG = "WIflySocket";

    EditText textOut;
    TextView textIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
         Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
         textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
         buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo == null || networkInfo.isConnected() == false) {
                   try {
                       throw new Exception("Network is not connected");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    new SocketThread(textOut.getText().toString()).execute();

                    textOut.setText("");
                }
            }};
}
```

and asynkTask:

```
package com.socket.wiflysocket;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class SocketThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private static final String TAG = "SocketAsyncTask";

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8;

    private String textViewIn;

    private String output;

    private Socket socket = null;

    private PrintWriter outputStream;

    private InputStreamReader inputStream;

    public SocketThread(String paramTextViewIn)
    {
        this.textViewIn = paramTextViewIn;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String ...views) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Execute");

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

         try {
            socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 2000);
            socket.setSoTimeout(2000);

            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            inputStream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

            if(socket.isConnected()) {

                this.sendDataWithString(textViewIn);

                output = this.receiveDataFromServer();
            }

            this.closeSocket();

         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally{
            if (socket != null){
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null){
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null){
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }

         return output;
    }
    /*
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        return textViewOut;
   }
    */

    private void closeSocket() {
        if (socket != null) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendDataWithString(String message) {
        if (message != null) {
            outputStream.write(message);
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    }

    private String receiveDataFromServer() {
        String message = "";
        try {
            int charsRead = 0;
            char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

            while ((charsRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                message += new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
            }

            closeSocket();
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            //TODO work around
            return message;
            //return "Error receiving response:  " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Permission that I add are :

`android.permission.INTERNET`;
`android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

Can you suggest me, what is wrong, and how to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: `inputStream.read()` blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Comment: When debug app I notice that, but how to get end of data? In debug mode I view send data to wifly in terminal(teraterm) connected to wifly with serial port. Data that was send from wifly is `Hello` but i get it when socket thrown exception. I am new in socket programing and dont know how to realize correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInput;    
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }
```

or this -

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
String line;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] chars = new char[4*1024];
int len;
while((len = r.read(chars))>=0) {
    sb.append(chars, 0, len);
}
```

or this one -

```
byte[] resultBuff = new byte[0];
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int k = -1;
while((k = sock.getInputStream().read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > -1) {
    byte[] tbuff = new byte[resultBuff.length + k];
    System.arraycopy(resultBuff, 0, tbuff, 0, resultBuff.length); bytes
    System.arraycopy(buff, 0, tbuff, resultBuff.length, k);
    resultBuff = tbuff; 
}
```

Comment: I try this code buy in all situation, thread freeze in read method and exit with socket timeout exeption. When removed `setSoTimeout`, and try to send again data, it is not received from wifly module and Log after read is not printed. Is this Jelly bean issue? Only workaround with exeption work but I can't check response and send data after check response code.

Answer (score 0):

SocketFactory creates socket for you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;

...

private Socket socket = null;
public Reader reader = null;
public Writer writer = null;

protected void init(String host, int port) throws ClientException {
    try {
        socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new ClientException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ClientException(e);
    }
    initDataManagers();
}
protected void initDataManagers() throws ClientException {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new ClientException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClientException(e);
        }   
}
```